# Setting location based on previous parameter of $routeChangeError with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm listening on events of the type $routeChangeError in a run block of my application.

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function (event, current, previous, rejection) {
    if (!!previous) {
        console.log(previous);
        $location.path(previous.$$route.originalPath);
    }        
});
```

With the help of the previous parameter I would like to set the location to the previous page. This works as long as the "originalPath" of "previous.$$route" does not contain any parameters. If it contains parameters the "originalPath" is not transformed.

Logging the previous objects returns the following output:

```
$$route: Object
   ...
   originalPath: "/users/:id"
   regexp: /^\/users\/(?:([^\/]+)?)$/
   ...
   params: Object
      id: "3"
```

How can I set the location to the previous path including the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

$route.previous.params contains the parameters of the previous path.